# Should I still worry about my Omega-3 to Omega 6 ratio when I consume other anti-inflammatory foods with my meals?

Tags: inflammation, omega-3, omega-6, anti-inflammatory

I hear that we must maintain a healthy ratio of Omega-3 to Omega-6 fats of at most 1:4 to avoid excessive inflammation in the body. However, Omega-3 fats are so hard to find in significant quantities in regular foods, and the few Omega-3 rich foods that do exist are pretty pricey.

So, I was thinking. Does the ratio still really matter that much when you're consuming other kinds of anti-inflammatory foods like cinnamon with your meals?

Wouldn't cinnamon, for example, serve the same purpose as Omega-3 fats as far as anti-inflammation goes that would allow me not to worry too much about the ratio of Omega-3 to Omega-6 fats?

Comment: @Narusan That question is not about the viability of replacing Omega-3 fats with other anti-inflammatory foods.

Comment: Agreed. Related: https://health.stackexchange.com/q/1297/8212

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why omega-3/6 ratio is important?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/why-omega-3-6-ratio-is-important)